# Why is my Tailwind CSS setup not working correctly with React Native?

Tags: css, react-native, tailwind-css

**app.js**

```
    import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
    import { Text, View } from 'react-native';
    
    
    export default function App() {
      return (
    
        <View className="flex-1 items-center justify-center" >
          <Text> Hello </Text>
          <StatusBar style="auto" />
        </View>
    
      );
    }
```

**tailwind.config.js**

```js
    module.exports = {
       content: ["./App.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}", "./screens/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}"],
        theme: {
          extend: {},
        },
        plugins: [],
      }
```

I have tried following the blogs and articles but I can't work it out

Comment: Please use the **edit** button to copy and paste the code, so that other users see the real code and not only a screenshot. Please also the rendered output.

Comment: I don't know your bug, but the common ones are: maybe try to be more generic something like this `"./*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}"`, or maybe your `className` is inside a file in `src/` so do `"./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}"`. or maybe you didn't start the terminal command `npx tailwindcss -i ./src/input.css -o ./dist/output.css --watch` (depend on which framework, for example in `svelteJS` we need to use this command but in `sveltekitJS` built-in inside `npm run dev`... but seems to me that you are using `react` so no need to this terminal command... maybe didn't include the 3 lines css `@tailwind`)

Comment: Please also include your `package.json` and the CSS file in which you're importing the Tailwind classes.